# How do I autofill a widget with form inputs using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm working on a donation form that has a widget embedded in it. The widget opts users into our Mobile Giving giving program which uses separate software than our donation forms. I've been asked to see if we can make the widget invisible but transfer the form data to it and submit it when the user submits the donation form. I've already run into a problem with getting the form data to transfer to the widget though.

The form should get the donors first name, last name and phone number from the form and then autofill the widget when a checkbox is clicked stating that the user would like to receive mobile updates.

Below is what I've tried but it doesn't seem to be working. The code for the form is relatively long so I just included the relevant fields but here is link to the full form: http://support.ddfl.org/site/Donation2?df_id=9442&mfc_pref=T&9442.donation=form1

I'm very new to Javascript so I'm not entirely sure if this is possible. Just an fyi, I also included console statements so I could see if the values were working.

```
<input type="text" name="billing_first_namename" id="billing_first_namename"

<input type="text" name="billing_last_namename" id="billing_last_namename"

<input type="text" name="donor_phonename" id="donor_phonename"

<input type="checkbox" name="mcoptin" onclick="FillMobileCause(this.form)" value="this.form"> Opt in to receive mobile updates.

<a href="//www.mobilecause.com/feature/subscription-widget" id="powered-by-mobilecause">Mobile messaging powered by Mobilecause</a><script>!function(d,s){var s=d.createElement("script"),h=(document.head||d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]);s.src="https://app.mobilecause.com/public/messaging_widgets/q71xd/source";h.appendChild(s);}(document);</script>

<script>
function FillMobileCause(f){
  if(f.mcoptin.checked == true){
    console.log(f.billing_first_namename.value);
    console.log(f.billing_last_namename.value);
    console.log(f.donor_phonename.value);

    if(f.billing_first_namename.value.length>=1){
       f.firstname.value = f.billing_first_namename.value;      

    }else {
       f.firstname.value = '';
    }

    if(f.billing_last_namename.length>=1){
       f.lastname.value = f.billing_last_namename.value;      
    }else{
       f.lastname.value = '';
    }

    if(f.donor_phonename.length>=1){
       f.mobilenumber.value = f.donor_phonename.value;      
    }else{
       f.mobilenumber.value = '';
    }

    console.log(f.firstname.value);
  }
}
</script>
```

Please let me know if I'm leaving off important details. This is also my first StackOverflow post. ;)

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You mean the widget lives at `//www.mobilecause.com/feature/subscription-widget` which iis not your server. If so, forget it. You need to do that on the server using curl or similar - unless they have an API supporting CORS

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you were referring to inputs in the mobilecause form as if they were in the same form, but they are in another (nested in your `f` main form).

```
function FillMobileCause(f){
  var mcF = f.getElementsByClassName('mc-triggersubscription')[0];

  if(f.mcoptin.checked == true){
    mcF.firstname.value = f.billing_first_namename.value;
    mcF.lastname.value = f.billing_last_namename.value;
    mcF.mobilenumber.value = f.donor_phonename.value;
  }
}
```

`f` is still the main form (the one that is the parent of the checkbox).

But now we have another one, `mcF` (mobilecauseForm), which is selected using the getElementsByClassName (this will search for a child with the `mc-triggersubscription` class). The `[0]` part is so the first match is selected (getElementsByClassName returns an array.

After that, all we need to do is assign the `f` inputs' values to the `mcF` ones.

Note: I left behind the "if empty" validation for simplifying. Anyway I don't think it's really needed, if a value is empty, there is no major issue in just copying it to the mobilecause value.